# Send chat invitatation to friend for group chat in android using asmack library

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack, chatroom

I am developing the chat application where one to one and group chat are the modules.

Currently i am able to implement the one to one chat.
I am able to create the new room for the group chat.

But i am unable to invite the friends to that group.

Can some one suggest on this?

here is the code i am using.

```
        setupMUC();

       MultiUserChat muc6 = new MultiUserChat(connection,"testroom@conference.im-pc-181/Smack");

         try {
             muc6.join("ashok");


             muc6.invite("kanakavaram@conference.im-pc-181/Smack", "Meet me in this excellent room");
                             muc6.addInvitationRejectionListener(new InvitationRejectionListener() {                    
                @Override
                public void invitationDeclined(String arg0, String arg1) {
                    Log.i(TAG,"invitationDeclined");
                }
            });

        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         catch (Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
```

Registering the listener.

```
  private void setupMUC() {
IMHelper.configure(ProviderManager.getInstance());
MultiUserChat.addInvitationListener(connection, new InvitationListener() {

    @Override
    public void invitationReceived(Connection arg0, String arg1, String arg2,
            String arg3, String arg4, Message arg5) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i(TAG,"u got it");
    }


    public void invitationReceived(XMPPConnection arg0, String arg1, String arg2,
            String arg3, String arg4, Message arg5) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i(TAG,"u got it XMPPConnection");
    }
});
```

}

Here the person who i am inviting is not getting the invitation and i am event not getting any exception while sending the invitation.

Comment: did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. It worked for me.

```
public void createInvitation(String room) throws XMPPException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // User2 joins the room

        muc.invite(room+"@localhost", "Meet me in this excellent room");
        muc.join(room);
        Log.d("adnan","gg : "+RoomMemberSelectAdapter.map);
    }
```